# Debugging Android App in Eclipse Doesn't Work

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I am new to Android development and also the Eclipse environment; I am used to using VS developing in C# so hopefully my issue will just be a configuration problem.

I am trying to use the debugger to step through my software.  I know how to add breakpoints and the software has to be ran in debug mode.  From here I should be able to use F5 & F6 to step in/over my breakpoint.

My issue is that these "Stepping" features don't seem to work.  My code stops at the breakpoint, but when I attempt to step past it nothing happens.  The highlighted line un-highlights, but then straight away is highlighted again; therefore I seem to never be able to step through my code.

I hope this issue makes sense and I appreciate any help that can be offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several situations when this might occur:

- The line is executed again, before the first occurrence is finished. This should only happen if you use recursion or that code is executed in parallel.
- You're stepping in and continue so far that it returns to outer method. This might happen when the line contains nested method calls: `getMyObject(getIdentifier(searchId("foobar"))`.
- The source code isn't matching the executed application. For example when using a decompiler or when the wrong source code version is attached.

For a precise answer, you should post the code and the steps you're taking.

---

If possible you should switch to [**Android Studio**](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) which is based on IntelliJ, because the Android Eclipse plugin was abandoned by Google.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my issue occurs even if I am on line 1 of my code.  I have just tested this by creating a brand new blank app (The default HelloWorld app); I put a breakpoint on line 1 "super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);" and I then try to step to line 2.  I get the same issue with this example.

Comment: The error log is blank.  I have tried using both the keyboard (pressing F5/F6 etc.) and the mouse (selecting the step in/over icons).  Weirdly if I remove the breakpoint once it has been reached, the step features now seem to work.  The breakpoint itself seems to be stopping it from moving to the next line; a bit strange but at least I can now debug my code, thanks for your help.